# Getting presence data from the Microsoft Graph API

Tags: microsoft-graph-api

I have been following the instructions to setup the **Microsoft Graph Webhooks Sample for Node.js** app here: https://github.com/microsoftgraph/nodejs-webhooks-rest-sample

However, when it tries to create the subscription I receive the following error:

```
Error: Operation: Create; Exception: [Status Code: BadRequest; Reason: Unsupported workload.]
at new GraphError (C:\Dev\nodejs-webhooks-rest-sample\node_modules\@microsoft\microsoft-graph-client\src\GraphError.ts:59:3)
at Function.GraphErrorHandler.constructErrorFromResponse (C:\Dev\nodejs-webhooks-rest-sample\node_modules\@microsoft\microsoft-graph-client\src\GraphErrorHandler.ts:62:18)
at Function.<anonymous> (C:\Dev\nodejs-webhooks-rest-sample\node_modules\@microsoft\microsoft-graph-client\src\GraphErrorHandler.ts:89:31)
at step (C:\Dev\nodejs-webhooks-rest-sample\node_modules\tslib\tslib.js:141:27)
at Object.next (C:\Dev\nodejs-webhooks-rest-sample\node_modules\tslib\tslib.js:122:57)
at C:\Dev\nodejs-webhooks-rest-sample\node_modules\tslib\tslib.js:115:75
at new Promise (<anonymous>)
at Object.__awaiter (C:\Dev\nodejs-webhooks-rest-sample\node_modules\tslib\tslib.js:111:16)
at Function.GraphErrorHandler.getError (C:\Dev\nodejs-webhooks-rest-sample\node_modules\@microsoft\microsoft-graph-client\lib\src\GraphErrorHandler.js:88:24)
at GraphRequest.<anonymous> (C:\Dev\nodejs-webhooks-rest-sample\node_modules\@microsoft\microsoft-graph-client\src\GraphRequest.ts:386:55)
```

My subscription configuration is as follows:

```
exports.subscriptionConfiguration = {
  changeType: 'updated',
  notificationUrl: 'https://123456789.ngrok.io/listen',
  resource: '/me/presence',
  clientState: 'SecretClientState',
  includeResourceData: false
};
```

and I have the following permissions associated with my Azure app:

[Azure app permissions](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SWplI.png)

Can anyone suggest what I am doing wrong?

Comment: Adding the related info in answer!! Let me know if this helps.

Answer (score 0):

I tried the following which worked for me. Sharing the related info:

1. This API (me/presence) uses the Presence.Read.All delegated permission - i see that you already specified it.
2. A signed-in user is required.
3. Follow these steps to set up a webhook and retrieve these notifications:

- Subscribe to a single user’s presence through the /communications/presences/{id} path.
- Subscribe to a maximum number of 650 users by using /communications/presences?$filter=id in ({id},{id}...).
- The {id} represents a user ID GUID.
- Subscriptions expire every hour and must be renewed.

Comment: Thanks Dev.

I hadn't actually added the Presence.Read.All permission, although it made no difference to the outcome.

Do you know what the resource should be to only retrieve my own presence?

Comment: Sorry, just saw you said  '/communications/presences/{id}'...if I replace my resource configuration with this (and {id} with my user's id) I receive the following error:  

Error: Operation: Create; Exception: [Status Code: Forbidden; Reason: The request is not authorized for this user or application.]